# How to save Word 2011 doc simultaneously in two different directories using Mac 10.8.4 Automator

Tags: macos, ms-word, automator

Newbie here.  I thought I knew enough about scripting for this, and have tried many Automator and AppleScript snippets from the Web without success.

I want to create a Mac OS X 10.8.4 Workflow/Service for MS Word 2011 to save a doc in two places simultaneously, i.e.:

1. Save the current Word doc to my laptop hard disk: 
   “Home Folder/[Specific Document Folder]/[Document Name]”.
2. Concurrently save the same document with the same name to my Dropbox folder:
   “Home Folder/Dropbox Folder/[Specific Document Folder]/[Document Name]”.

The paths are identical except for the insertion of the “Dropbox Folder” in the path name.

I want to build a Workflow that requires no user input other than one initial key combo or toolbar click to save a Word doc (no matter which doc I’m working on, no matter which folder) to both its current folder and to its Dropbox folder.

I’ve searched for, but can’t find, an Action in Automator to Get the current MS Word doc’s full path and name; the only Action I’ve found returns just the name. I suspect I need to insert a Run Script Action into my Workflow, but I don’t know how to write the script to get the path name, and then insert the “Dropbox Folder” text into that path name for Automator's Save As Action.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks much.

Comment: I'm looking at it, but I'm curious.  What have you tried?  Will you post some code (even if it doesn't work).  That would be a start.

Comment: What if you developed a "Folder Action" in Automator and the Run AppleScript action.  Then you could attach your folder action software to your specified document folder and the AppleScript would run and and would automatically make a copy of the file in your Dropbox folder.  This would work for any application -- not just for Word.  What do you think?  You can emal me at: kaydell@yahoo.com.